# How important is it to arrange the data by person ID, lab name and lab date before calculating min, med and max values of a lab

Tags: r, statistics

I am wondering how important is it to arrange the data by person ID, lab name and lab date before calculating min, med and max values of a lab? I have noticed that arranging big data in R takes a lot of time, and I would like to avoid that if not needed. This is the code that I am running:

```
tmpdf<-tmpdf %>% 
arrange(person_id, lab_name, date) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(person_id, lab_name) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(total_values= max(row_number())) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    min_value = round(as.numeric(min(lab_value, na.rm = T)), digits = 2),
    max_value = round(as.numeric(max(lab_value, na.rm = T)), digits = 2),
    med_value = round(as.numeric(median(lab_value, na.rm = T)), digits = 2)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Always include the relevant programming language tag with your question.